# Cannot initialise a parameter of type QMainWindow: ui->setupUi(this) error

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to Qt. I have from the link

https://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QNetworkRequest_Http_File_Download.php

the code because I want to learn about **QNewtorkRequest** class.

But when I execute the code I get the error below:

[image]

here is a part of the source code:

```
#include "httpdownload.h"
#include "ui_httpdownload.h"

HttpDownload::HttpDownload(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::HttpDownload)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->urlEdit->setText("http://qt.com");
    ui->statusLabel->setWordWrap(true);
    ui->downloadButton->setDefault(true);
    ui->quitButton->setAutoDefault(false);

    progressDialog = new QProgressDialog(this);

    connect(ui->urlEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),
                this, SLOT(enableDownloadButton()));
    connect(progressDialog, SIGNAL(canceled()), this, SLOT(cancelDownload()));
}
```

Here is the ui file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>HttpDownload</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="HttpDownload">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>580</width>
    <height>204</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: post the source code please...

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I add it.

Comment: Also show the .ui file you are using. For some reason it is expecting a QMainWindow instead of a QDialog, but it is correct at the source.

Comment: @Botje, the .ui file is added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's your problem. The ui file expects a QMainWindow but your C++ code defines a QDialog. Choose one and fix the other.

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't pay attention to this before.